# Algorithm on finding the minimum edge rewiring for isomorphic graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let us denote the original graph $G_O$ and the target graph $G_T$.

I am wondering if there exists an algorithm that uses the minimum number of edge deletions and additions to make $G_0$ isomorphic to $G_T$.

I have been searching for a bit and found graph matching as the closest thing, but it only checks if two graphs are isomorphic. Can anyone give me some directions or references? Thank you

Comment: Why should this minimum exist? Do you allow edge-deletions in both $G_0$ and $G_T$? What if they have different amounts of vertices?

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to finding the [*maximum common subgraph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_common_edge_subgraph).

A solution that removes $b$ edges and adds $c$ edges means that $G_0$ and $G_T$ both have a subgraph isomorphic to the same $G_\text{mid}$ with $|E(G_0)| - b = |E(G_T)| - c$ edges (the graph obtained after removing but before adding edges). Conversely, a common subgraph $G_\text{mid}$ means there is a solution removing $|E(G_0)| - |E(G_\text{mid})|$ edges and then adding $|E(G_T)| - |E(G_\text{mid})|$ edges, for a total of $|E(G_0)| + |E(G_T)| - 2|E(G_\text{mid})|$. Since $|E(G_0)| + |E(G_T)|$ is fixed, minimizing the number of additions and deletions is the same as maximizing $|E(G_\text{mid})|$.

Wikipedia calls it *Maximum common edge subgraph* for disambiguation, but most references just say *maximum common subgraph* without *edge*.

Note that the problem is NP-hard, because even [finding a clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) of given size is NP-hard (*the clique [decision] problem*). A graph $G$ contains $K_n$ iff you can add/remove $|E(G)|-|E(K_n)|$ edges to $K_n$ to obtain a graph isomorphic to $G$.